# Make long log data diplayed with PHP easy to read

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a long log file I am displaying with PHP. Its getting too long for me and I have to use CTRL+F to look at this thing in any way. What is a good way to display this data in a way easy to read?
Best way would be using jquery.

Comment: Its just a long list of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your problem seems to be **client-side searching-and-filtering** your log (since you use a lot of Ctrl+F), you could use the **[quicksearch](http://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch#readme)** jquery plugin (see the example on the page).

Now in the examples, the plugin filters table rows, but I believe you could also use it to filter other type of elements, such as `<p>log message</p>`. Just wrap individual messages in an appropriate html element, and then filter them.

Comment: This seems very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably in a tabular format. Personally, jQuery + [dataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) (jQuery plugin) works really well for most applications where you can sort out times and types of messages and such. dataTables would allow you to say, view 100 per page and sort by it.

Comment: It seems pretty good. I'll try it but i think quicksearch fits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Define 'long'. Is the data being displayed in a very long string that makes you scroll horizontally?

If so you could try breaking it down using something like:

```
echo nl2br($very_long_log_file);
```

which will put a `<br/>` before all new lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide an interactive "search" field at the top that would filter the long list of lines to show only the lines matching the search criteria. This could be done on the client side with using jQuery which would avoid a round-trip to the server.